# Magento can't login in admin and user level

Tags: php, magento, ssl

I've got a problem with my Magento webshop. The webshop is running for almost a year. And about a month ago, the webshop moved to a new server. But now I'm starting to have problems with the login. I can not login to the admin panel and customers can no longer log into the customer panel.

It seems that the page just refreshed and does nothing

Link to admin-panel login:
http://goo.gl/5ScNst

Link to customer-panel login:
http://goo.gl/9vU7Ru

Looks like customer login only works with http:// instead of https://.. Maybe it's caused by ssl?

Thank you very much!

Edit: Now I find out that there is one more strange issue on my webshop. When a customer add a product to the cart, the cart shows that there's nothing in there. Very strange! What happened to my webshop? Didn't edit anything

Comment: Have you upgraded your magento version?

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed your webshop URL this link would help: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data. The webshop URL and the URL values in the core_config_data table need to match.

Now if you left your webshop URL intact after you have moved your webshop, maybe you can delete the folders inside var/cache directory in your webshop directory. Magento will recreate the cache files for you the next time you access the admin and front page.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I left my URL intact, and deleting folders inside /var/cache doesn't give any result..

Comment: Are you sure the var/cache you deleted is inside your webshop folder. It seems you have a leading slash in your directory. /var/cache is different from var/cache.

Comment: Yes I did the correct folder, var/cache. But now I'm in the var/ folder, I see that var/session is empty.. should this really be empty?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to tell you that you can also delete the session folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar login problems on server change and after I switched "redirect_to_baseurl" off, everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't do anything in phpmyadmin! So I guess that's the problem! I can't enter a query without error, can't search, even can't see tables (only the first 30 rows). So I've to check out at a problem in mysql